# Is there an API in Kubernetes which can fetch all volumes of a specific AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

Was unable to find any K8s API which can query all volumeIDs related to specific AWS account region wide. My primary intention is to clean all stale volumes. For doing this, I'm collecting volume information from AWS which are in Available state using below shell script.

```
  for regions in $(aws ec2 describe-regions --output text|awk {'print $4'})
  do
     for volumes in $(aws ec2 describe-volumes --region $regions --output text| grep available | awk '{print $9}' | grep vol| tr '\n' ' ')
      do
          echo "$regions" "$volumes"
          done
  done
```

But that alone isn't sufficient as sometimes I keep some of my environments down and that time pods are not running which in turn marks the volumes as *Available* but they will be *in use*/attached to pods once the environment comes up. Hence, I need to get both the lists (from AWS and K8s) and diff them. Finally, I get the volumes which are actually not associated to any of my environments. Any help is greatly appreciated.

N.B: It is known the below k8s API can fetch volumes taking namespaces as input which I'm not looking for.

```
GET /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/persistentvolumeclaims
```

Answer (score 1):

Two answers: first you can `kubectl get pvc —all-namespaces`. Second, the PVs themselves are not in namespaces so `kubectl get pv`.

Comment: I'm not at all planning to use kubectl as I will have to login to the master node of each cluster and run that. I'm looking for a solution which will provide collective result from all my cluster on my account level region wide.

Comment: I don’t know what you mean, but all scoped API calls you can just leave off the namespace. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/ for the standards.